# how to debug QuantLib?

Tags: quantlib

I have installed QuantLib on Mac.
I also compiled the bermudaswaption successfully, as an example.

I tried to modify/debug the code of QuantLib like analyticeuropeanengine.cpp when code reviewing.

But when modifying the code like analyticeuropeanengine.cpp, I would need to re-make / install all the project, and that costs a lot of time.

How I can do this efficiently?

Comment: Lots of general ways of speeding up builds like ccache. Most make projects should only rebuild the changed object files. Typically you don't make install if you are editing the library, and instead directly use the built object files/library files in your build dir. Can you clarify how long it is currently taking to build, check other questions about optimizing build times, and clarify what your target build time is.

Comment: opps...quite simple...using cmake seems well

Comment: If another stackoverflow question answered your question, please link/flag as a duplicate. Otherwise consider answering your own question for future question askers.